# fancybox ajax post to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, fancybox

is it possible using [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) to post a var to the iframe when opens?

I currently have:

```
function fancyBoxLoad(element) {
    var elementToEdit = $("#" + $(element).attr("class"));
    var content = encodeURIComponent($(elementToEdit).outerHTML());
    $.fancybox(
        { 'href': 'loadEditor.php' },
        {
            frameWidth: 750,
            frameHeight: 430,
            overlayShow: true,
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                data: 'content=' + content
            },
            type: 'iframe'
        }
    );
}
```

It does seem that if I take away `type: 'iframe'` it will post data but it doesn't appear to be in the iframe and if I take away `ajax: { type: "POST", data: 'content=' + content }` instead it will open in an iframe but not post the data (the example above does the same)

So my question being can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to put content in a iframe, why don't you use fancybox to create the iframe, and once you know it's been created, then access it via the reference that fancybox returns to you and set your content that way.  I'm not sure you want to send the content to the server and back.  Just wait for the iframe to load, then on ready, query an element within it and set the content.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for Fancybox v1.3.1 they are in fact mutually exclusive.  If you don't feel comfortable diving into the source code and editing the plugin, you might try using [GET variables in your HREF](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/Q/query_string.html) as a work around.  It should effectively work like a post as it is an AJAX call, just make sure the backend can receive the GET variables.

Comment: An example would be `{ 'href': 'loadEditor.php?content' + content }`.

Comment: Also, is it an AJAX call?  (I'm not that familiar with the plugin.)